# ISAPI Rewrite : Append querystring to the rewrited URl's Query String

Tags: isapi-rewrite

Actually, using the following ISAPI rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/Product-name/$ /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L]
```

I'm rewriting the following URL

```
htttp://www.domain.com/Product-name/
```

to

```
htttp://www.domain.com/test.cfm?ProducID=xxxx
```

This is working fine, But when I use the querystring in URL, it is not working

For Egs:
The following URL is not working

```
htttp://www.domain.com/Product-name?categoryID=YYYY
```

I need to rewrite the above URL as follows

```
htttp://www.domain.com/test.cfm?ProducID=xxxx&categoryID=YYYY
```

I've used the following rule, but no luck

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(\d+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/Product-name/$ /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx?param2=%1? [NC,L]
```

So is there any solution for this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as ColdFusion?

Comment: @ScottStroz It is Coldfusion application, so tagged. Nothing other than that.

Comment: But the problem is not, in any way, related to ColdFusion.

Comment: Yes you are correct, Thanks for removing the Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rule, appends the query string to the rewritten URL's Querystring and avoids the 404 error

**URL With Querystring and Trailing slash(/)**

```
RewriteRule ^/Product-name/\? /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L,QSA]
```

**URL With Querystring and Without Trailing slash(/)**

```
RewriteRule ^/Product-name\? /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L,QSA]
```

**URL Without Querystring and with Trailing slash(/)**

```
RewriteRule ^/Product-name/$ /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L]
```

**URL Without Querystring and Trailing slash(/)**

```
RewriteRule ^/Product-name$ /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ISAPI_Rewrite 3, then you should add QSA flag to append original query string to the resulting URL:

```
RewriteRule ^/Product-name/$ /test.cfm?ProductID=xxxx [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes I'm using Helicon ISAPI_ Rewrite3, But this rule is not working for me, same 404 Error.